# Learning to Rank with no queries

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

I want to rank (order by relevance) some data, and I currently have some labeled observations (relevance scores given by a user) and some unlabeled observations.

I'm currently studying learning to rank and I've a doubt: from [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/hangli/l2r.pdf) I can see that the training set for ltr is formed by queries and documents, but are learning to rank techniques usable when there are no query (=> I only need to rank some data, there are no queries)?

I've seen that exists an approach called "bipartite ranking" that ranks using -1 and +1 values to get the final ranking. What's the relation of this technique with learning to rank?

It seems like I can't get my head around this, can you point me some resources that will help me understand this concepts better?

Comment: It depends, you can think these data all in one query. Such as, you learn ctr, and use it for ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on the learning to rank algorithm you are going to use.
I suggest you to study it and evaluate how the queryId is affecting it.
It could be that the queryIds are used to group training entries and optimize the model per query.
It could be that the queryIds are used to group the test data and an average  of the test score per query is then returned.
I will use LambdaMART and I have no queries.
This means that I will generate the queryId pseudo randomly or with similar approach.

Cheers